# Querying my JPA provider (Hibernate) for a collection of <Id,Name> of an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, composite

I have an entity which looks something like this:
Id  (PK)
Name
Other business properties and associations...

I have the need for my DAL (JPA with hibernate as provider) to return a list of the entities which correlate to some constraints (or just return them all) but instead of returning the entities themselves I'd like to receive only the Id and the Name properties.
I know this can be achieved with HQL/SQL (something like: select id,name from entity where...) but I don't want to go down that road.
I was thinking of somehow defining the  pair a compositioned part of the entity and thought that might help me but I'm not sure that's "legal" as the Id is the PK.
The logic for this scenario is to have a textbox which asynchronously queries the web-service (and through it the DAL) for the relevant entities and once an entity is selected then it is loaded as a whole and shipped to the front-end.

**Update:**
I am now pretty confident I'll be using the CriteriaBuilder interface of JPA to build queries and so JPQL/HQL is completely off the table.
I think I might be looking for JPA's equivalent to Hibernate's resultTransformer (and I'll give it a non persisted class).

Would appreciate any feedback,
Ittai

Comment: Why exactly do you not want to use HQL/JPAQL?

Comment: I don't like the fact that query does not compile which can generate erros when properties change (and it can be harder to note)

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry ignore this as I missed "dont want to do HQL" part in your question*

The HQL select clause is very flexible. If you need just two properties you can use

```
select new MyClass(foo.id,foo.name) From Foo foo
```

where MyClass is your java class with constructor (id,name).

If you don't want to create separate class, HQL can return array of type Object.

```
select foo.id,foo.name From Foo foo
```

Please read the detail about select clause [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) from documentation

Comment: +1 - I didn't know that it is possible to use `new` keyword in HQL

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement I guess HQL or JPQL is the best option and how often you will change the field names? 
You can use @NamedQuery to hold the HQL in the same entity class so you won't miss that change if you change the Field names.